# SyntaxError: Can't assign to function call while converting matlab code to Python

Tags: python, matlab

Hi I have a block of code in Matlab. I am aiming to convert it to Python as shown below. But the python code gives me the following error. Could you please help me to find out the syntax error here.

Matlab Code:

```
for j = 1:length(Filters)
    if j == 1
        Shifts(1) = int16(-(round(log2(sqrt(size(Filters{j},3))*2/16))));
        Shifts(1) = Shifts(1)-int16(4);
    elseif j < length(Filters)
        Shifts(j) = int16(-(round(log2(sqrt(size(Filters{j},3))*2/16))));
    end
```

Python Translation:

```
for j in range(0,len(Filters)):
    if j == 1:
        Shifts(1) = np.int16(-(np.round(np.log2(np.sqrt(len(Filters[j][3])*2/16)))))
        Shifts(1) = Shifts(1) - np.int16(4)
    elif  j < len(Filters):
        Shifts(j) = np.int16(-(np.round(np.log2(np.sqrt(len(Filters[j][3])*2/16)))))
```

Is there a  better way to represent my code in Python.

Comment: `Shifts(x)` should be `Shifts[x]`

Comment: The `elif` can be simplified to `else`.

Comment: Thanks I overlooked those brackets.

Comment: I would also guess that a test for `j==1` in MATLAB, should be converted to `j==0` in python....